# PowerLine fonts in Console Apps

Tags: c#, fonts, console-application, powerline

i'm working on a console app that recreates CMD in Windows. I want to
support powerline fonts, but couldn't find the standard charaters used to display the arrows. Is there a list with all the default arrow types? Thanks!

[image: Example of terminal with powerline font and arrows.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did more research, so apparently you need to enable unicode in the console window: `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;`, and then you can use unicode symbols.